# Captcha image is not rendering in sitecore web form for marketers

Tags: webforms, sitecore, captcha, web-forms-for-marketers

I am using "**Web Forms for Marketers 2.5 rev. 141014**", while **creating a form** I am taking a **Captcha field**, but **captcha image is not rendering on front end**.

[Screenshot Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/baqtJ.png)

What am i doing wrong??

Comment: Are you running on LiveMode (i.e single IIS instance) for your CM and front-end instance? Or have you deployed the WFFM CD package to your front-end server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for your suggestions, but the problem were with dll conflict. When I first installed the WFFM module (which contains Captcha dll) and then after installing the WeBlog module (which also contains Captcha dll), the dll were over written. So trying with [assembly redirect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7wd6ex19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) resolved this issue. Thanks again for your contribution.

Answer (score 4):

Have you modified Web.config as requested in post installation steps?

> 4. Add the following nodes to the Web.config:
>
>    - for IIS 6.x under the configuration\system.web\httpHandlers node
>    - for IIS 7.x and up under the configuration\system.webServer\handlers node

If you did then do you use both WFFM and WeBlog module?

The problem is that WeBlog uses preprocessRequest sitecore pipeline to resolve CaptchaImage. This pipeline does not have Session prepared so WFFM captcha (which stores data in session by default) will not work in such a setup.

The solution was just to remove the

```
<preprocessRequest>
  <processor patch:before="*[1]" type="Sitecore.Modules.WeBlog.Pipelines.CaptchaProcessor,Sitecore.Modules.WeBlog"/>
</preprocessRequest>
```

from the WeBlog.config file.

Comment: But what functionality of WeBlog is lost by removing this line from `WeBlog.config`?

Answer (score 3):

Found this article by Jonathan Robbins [Web Forms for Marketers Captcha not displaying](http://jonathanrobbins.co.uk/2015/03/23/sitecore-web-forms-for-marketers-captcha-not-rendering-correctly/) that solved my problem

It turns out there are additional configuration that need to be added to the web.config when installing or updating this version of Web Forms.

If your site is running on II7 and has Management Pipeline Mode is set to Integrated you will want to add theses configuration nodes at the bottom of the following location in the web.config configuration/system.webServer/handers

```xml
<add name="CaptchaImage" verb="*" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="Sitecore.Form.Core.Pipeline.RequestProcessor.CaptchaResolver, Sitecore.Forms.Core" />
<add name="CaptchaAudio" verb="*" path="CaptchaAudio.axd" type="Sitecore.Form.Core.Pipeline.RequestProcessor.CaptchaResolver, Sitecore.Forms.Core" />
```

If your site is running on IIS6 or the Managed Pipeline of your Application Pool is Classic these two nodes needs to be added to the following path in the web.config configuration/system.webServer/httpHanders

```xml
<add name="CaptchaImage" verb="*" path="CaptchaImage.axd" type="Sitecore.Form.Core.Pipeline.RequestProcessor.CaptchaResolver, Sitecore.Forms.Core" />
<add name="CaptchaAudio" verb="*" path="CaptchaAudio.axd" type="Sitecore.Form.Core.Pipeline.RequestProcessor.CaptchaResolver, Sitecore.Forms.Core" />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using MVC there might be a problem with the Microsoft Captcha control. Sitecore has released a hotfix that you could get by contacting support at http://support.sitecore.net

http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers/Web%20Forms%20for%20Marketers%202,-d-,5/Release%20Notes.aspx

Comment: Can u provide for me the hotfix ?